# Asynchronous load data in counter bug

Tags: timer, load, vhdl, counter

I build a counter with asynchronous load in VHDL. When i press the button(which should load data in counter) it will not increment the data but it will go like that: if the counter displays 10 -> 1, 11->2, etc.. 
It works fine when i press the button repeatedly but if i left the button a while the next time when i press it will not work fine.
My counter:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity countfeed is
    Port ( Clock : in STD_LOGIC;
           Num_out : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
           ECU : in STD_LOGIC;
           ALoad: in STD_LOGIC;
           data : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
           ECD : in STD_LOGIC);
end countfeed;

    architecture Behavioral of countfeed is
    signal count : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0) := X"0000";
    begin

    Num_out <= count;


    process(Clock,ALoad)
    begin
        if(ALoad = '1') then
            count <= data;
        elsif(rising_edge(Clock)) then
            if(ECU = '1') then
                if(count(3 downto 0) = X"9") then
                    count(3 downto 0) <= X"0";
                    count(7 downto 4) <= count(7 downto 4) + 1;
                else
                    count(3 downto 0) <= count(3 downto 0) + 1;
                end if;
                if(count(7 downto 0) =  X"59") then
                    count(7 downto 0) <= X"00";
                    count(11 downto 8) <= count(11 downto 8) + 1;
                end if;
                if(count(11 downto 0) = X"959") then
                    count(11 downto 0) <= X"000";
                    count(15 downto 12) <= count(15 downto 12) + 1;
                end if;
                if(count(15 downto 0) = X"9959") then
                    count(15 downto 0) <= X"0000";
                end if;
            elsif(ECD = '1') then
                if(count(3 downto 0) = X"0") then
                    if(count(15 downto 4) /= X"0") then
                        count(3 downto 0) <= X"9";
                        count(7 downto 4) <= count(7 downto 4) - 1;
                        if(count(7 downto 4) = X"0") then
                            if(count(15 downto 8) /= X"0") then
                                count(7 downto 4) <= X"5";
                                count(11 downto 8) <= count(11 downto 8) - 1;
                                if(count(11 downto 8) = X"0") then
                                    if(count(15 downto 12) /= X"0") then
                                        count(11 downto 8) <= X"9";
                                        count(15 downto 12) <= count(15 downto 12) - 1;
                                    end if;
                                end if;
                            end if;
                        end if;
                    end if;
                else
                    count(3 downto 0) <= count(3 downto 0) - 1;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if; 
    end process;   

    end Behavioral;
```

My data processing(where bS is the button, disp_n the output of the counter, data is the data to load:

```
process(bS)
begin
    if(rising_edge(bS)) then
    data(15 downto 8) <= disp_n(15 downto 8);
    if(disp_n(7 downto 0) = X"59") then
        data(7 downto 0) <= X"00";
    elsif(disp_n(3 downto 0) = X"9") then
        data(3 downto 0) <= X"0";
        data(7 downto 4) <= disp_n(7 downto 4) + 1;
    else
        data(3 downto 0) <= disp_n(3 downto 0) + 1;
    end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

Load:

```
ALoad <= bS;
```

toplevel:

```
architecture Behavioral of toplevel is

Component ClockDivider is...


Component BCD is...


Component DebouncerC is...


Component edge_det is...


Component countfeed is
    Port ( Clock : in STD_LOGIC;
           Num_out : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
           ECU : in STD_LOGIC;
           ALoad: in STD_LOGIC;
           data: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
           ECD: in STD_LOGIC);
end Component;





signal bSS,bS,bM : STD_LOGIC; --Debounced buttons
signal clk1s : STD_LOGIC; -- 1 Hz Clock
signal ECU,ECD : STD_LOGIC; -- Enable Count Up/Down
signal Reset : STD_LOGIC; -- Reset
signal disp_n: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
signal ALoad: STD_LOGIC;
signal data: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
signal btS,btM: STD_LOGIC;
signal dataS: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
begin
--Execution Unit--
E0: ClockDivider port map( Clock => Clock, ClockDiv => clk1s);
E1: BCD port map( Number => disp_n, Clock => Clock, Anod => Anod, Segment => seg);
E2: DebouncerC port map( Clock => Clock, Button_in => StartStop, Button_out => bSS);
E3: DebouncerC port map( Clock => Clock, Button_in => Seconds, Button_out => bS);
E4: DebouncerC port map( Clock => Clock, Button_in => Minutes, Button_out => bM);
E5: Reset <= bS and bM;
E6: countfeed port map(Clock => clk1s, Num_out => disp_n,ECU => ECU,
                        ECD => ECD,ALoad => ALoad, data => data);
E7: edge_det port map (Clock => Clock, Signal_in => bS, Signal_out => btS);
E8: edge_det port map (Clock => Clock, Signal_in => bM, Signal_out => btM);

ALoad <= btS or btM;


process(bS)
begin
    if(rising_edge(bS)) then
    data(15 downto 8) <= disp_n(15 downto 8);
    if(disp_n(7 downto 0) = X"59") then
        data(7 downto 0) <= X"00";
    elsif(disp_n(3 downto 0) = X"9") then
        data(3 downto 0) <= X"0";
        data(7 downto 4) <= disp_n(7 downto 4) + 1;
    else
        data(3 downto 0) <= disp_n(3 downto 0) + 1;
    end if;
    end if;
end process;

process(bSS)
begin
if(rising_edge(bSS)) then
ECU <= not ECU;
end if;
end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Where are your `library` and `use` clauses? Post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Note that you can not simply and reliably asynchronous load multiple bits. This ` process(Clock,ALoad) begin  if(ALoad = '1') then  count <= data;...` is fundamentally flawed if `ALoad` is asynchronous to your clock.

Comment: So i can't increment the counter using ALoad? I want to increment a counter asynchronous from a pushbutton. But the counter has another clock. Is there another way doing that?

Comment: Simple: make sure all signals including `ALoad` are synchronous to your clock by synchronizing them. Also do NOT use any other clocks, so do not us `if(rising_edge(bS)) `. Again synchronize  `bs` to your clock, make a edge detector and use the clock.

Comment: If i sync the button it will increment at The next rising edge of the clock but i dont want that. I want to increment immediately after i press The button.

Comment: If you're using a clk over 1kHz, which is very likely, you'll never see the difference between using the asynchronous signal or the next clock edge...

Comment: Im using a clock with 1Hz, so is obvious

Comment: You are doing some really weird stuff. I guess your 1 Hz is synthetized under the Hood using a counter.
Why do you not just make everything synchronous ? Is it experimental ?

Comment: Nope. It is a Project on school. I solved The problem using another clock of 5Hz, so when i press The button it will Change The clock and increment with 5 per second.